# Which is my live and neutral?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

We're following singaporean wiring code, which is roughly in line with the UK code. We use 220v everywhere

We have an older light fixture that was converted from CCFL to LEDs by a proper electrician, and over the years we've swapped out the bulbs. We've generally 'just' followed the wiring they did - and they'd used a snap-apart terminal block we very religiously followed. The block's suffering from plastic fatigue and I have swapped it out for a set of lever terminals. The entire place was rewired in the 90 or early 2000s if I recall. For extra fun, I *distinctly* remember seeing red wires at a switch elsewhere in the apartment.

While doing so I noticed that there's a pair of black wires in the neutral terminal of the old block, and a brown one. The brown is labelled live, and the black ones neutral. We follow the UK system so I'm assuming there's a ring loop.

[image]

Looking at the local colour codes (singapore) - which are identical to the UK codes (and [we changed from old to new/IEC code in 2009](https://repairs.sg/electrical-wire-colour-code-singapore/))

[image]

This is *after* the replacement - with the new lever nuts

This doesn't seem to match any code I'm in. As far as I'm aware my building has single phase, 220v power.

Unfortunately I need a time machine to figure out what's going on, and rewiring the whole place 'to code' isn't really an option for the moment? I treat all wires as "likely to kill me, and hurt badly while its doing it" - and am unlikely to need to rewire a socket, but this feels like a useful bit of information to work out.

How do I confirm which is which, and is there any way to work this out?

Comment: Quick note - yes, those are knockoff wago-style lever nuts. They seem reasonably solid, and I'll be monitoring this install for a bit. Its actually a fair bit more robust than the 'clip' style connectors that came with the replacement LED fixture I was installing.

Comment: Those color coded levers are intriguing. Could it be that this block isn't an connector, one that inter-connects those three wires, but an attachments points for three wires to something like an terminal?

Comment: Oh those are the new ones - not the old ones - which were just a single 3 pin block that looked like a molex connector. Its not about the blocks its about the wires. The lever blocks were just a neater way to put 3 wires together than jamming 2 thick wires into one screw block as the original was. Also felt it made for easier swaps in future since its tool-less

Comment: Really hard to tell from the photo, but you have two cables, each with three wires. Ignoring earths, the two browns gang together, sending live to your switch; of the two blacks, one is neutral, the other is the return from the switched live circuit. One goes to each side of your lamp. The switch loop is supposed to be two browns, one tagged with tape… but no-one ever does. If your fittings use edisons, then use a multimeter so see which cable is permanent live. If bayonet or LED, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: btw, I can't tell how your Wago thingies are supposed to work, but all those green earths should be ganged too.

Comment: Oh they are already - the wire colors are unambiguous though. I have 2 blacks, one brown and 2 Earth's coming out the ceiling. One earth connected to the metal light fixture ganged the ceiling Earths with a 3 port lever nut connector, one of the wires from the light + the 2 blacks on another, and one 2 port with brown and the second light wire.

Comment: I'm lost, in two cables you only have 1 brown, but two blacks? How many cables come in there? Should be two, each with a 3-wire 'set' of the same colours.

Comment: 5 - one brown 2 black, 2 earth.. they all seem to be individual wires not a combined cable

Comment: Then I can't help, sorry. Makes no sense to me. I'd have to get a sparky in to have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your picture it seems that the black-black-white(?) triple is the neutral, and the brown-grey pair is the switched(?) phase. The second black wire on the triple is probably going to the next junction.

The two black wires would be the old color code for neutral. The brown wire could be an newer wire for the switched-phase, to supply the lights.

To confirm that, one would need to disconnect the light, and measure the tension between the suspected neutral and ground, then the tension between the suspected phase and ground, on the live circuit, with lights switched on. Suitable devices are CATII multimeters or two-prong testers. It seems those lever connectors have an hole on the end, where one can place a multimeter probe. 220-240V against ground is the switched on phase, about 0 against ground is the neutral **OR** the switched off phase.

If you don't feel confident to measure on the live circuit should consult an electrician. I don't know your local electrical codes, but I strongly assume you have both proper breakers and RCD-devices. Should those be missing, refrain from doing any electrical works.

Comment: We have both proper breakers and RCD devices. .The 'thinner' wires are for the light, and I followed the markings that were on previously - I *think* someone else swapped out the light the last time.  The wierd thing is all the rewiring was done at once and we did *not* retain any of the old wiring, so the 'mixed' code makes no sense.  And yeah, these have holes for testing.  The wires on the light are white and grey

Comment: Also, I'm fairly confident in my own skills. My multimeter and most of my 'proper' electronics kit however is ... somewhat dodgy and I don't trust them

Comment: The two blacks - one is switched live [return], the other is [mains] neutral.  Of the two browns, one is permanent [mains] live, the other is the feed to the switch - which also makes it a permanent live, because it's ganged directly to the incoming power. To find which is which pair, with power off isolate them all  & test continuity on each pair using a meter & the light switch. That way, you're not playing with 240V at all.

Comment: There's only one brown.

Comment: mhm, as comments above… now I'm stumped. I wouldn't know what to make of that setup.